# How to get distinct items from a Scala Iterable, maintaining laziness

Tags: scala, collections, lazy-evaluation

I have a `java.lang.Iterable` which computes its values lazily. I am accessing it from Scala. Is there a core API way of returning only distinct values? For instance, imaging there was a filter method that also provided all results returned thus far:

```
val myLazyDistinctIterable = iterable.filter((previousReturnedItems, newItem) => previousReturnedItems.contains(newItem))
```

I guess this is not a very general case because it involves storing previously returned items, and that might be why it isn't in the core API.

I know about `List.distinct` and `Set`s but I want something that will not compute its elements until asked.

Comment: I think the easiest way to do this would be to return an iterator with a mutable `Set` in its closure that keeps track of what it's seen, and then is generated by `filter` applied to its input, updating the seen set and returning false as appropriate.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `distinct` method on [`Stream`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Stream). For example, if you have this `Iterable`:

```
val it = new java.lang.Iterable[Int] {
  def iterator = new java.util.Iterator[Int] {
    var i = 0
    var first = true

    def hasNext = true
    def next =
      if (first) { first = false; i } else { first = true; i += 1; i - 1 }
    def remove() { throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Can't remove.") }
  }
}
```

You can write:

```
scala> import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

scala> val s = it.asScala.toStream
s: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(0, ?)

scala> s.take(10).toList
res0: List[Int] = List(0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4)

scala> val s = it.asScala.toStream.distinct
s: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(0, ?)

scala> s.take(10).toList
res1: List[Int] = List(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
```

We can tell that everything is appropriately lazy since the stream is infinite.

Comment: D'oh, should've checked Stream. Thanks. I remember now that Stream stores its previously returned items. I thought that was an implementation detail originally but I guess it's part of its semantics too.

Comment: have you ever tried to use Scalas own distinct? x.toList.distinct

Answer (score 8):

**UPDATE** Reading questions carefully is good. No laziness in this solution. Sorry.

`toSet` will do exactly what you want:

1. Store iterated elements in a collection (not what you want but required)
2. Drop / Replace duplicates

Example

```
val it = Seq(1,2,3,4,2,4): Iterable[Int]
it.toSet
// Set(1,2,3,4)
```

If you feel fancy, you can convert that back to an iterable:

```
it.toSet.toIterable
```

Or, pimp the `Iterable`:

```
implicit class UniquableIterable[T](t: Iterable[T]) {
  def unique = t.toSet.toIterable
}
```

And then call

```
it.unique
```

Comment: No worries, guess you're just not a lazy person ;)

Comment: @DanGravell Yep... I don't think you'll get around writing a `UniqueIterable` with really ugly internal state.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on my comment above, but I can't test it right now:

```
def unique[A](it: Iterator[A]): Iterator[A] = {
  val seen = mutable.Set[A]()
  it.filter { a =>
    if (seen(a))
      false
    else {
      seen += a
      true
    }
  }
}
```

You get the idea, at least. You would then apply this to the iterator you get from your iterable, and not get the unnecessary storage behavior of `Stream`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that adds `.disctinct` method to `Iterator`.

```
implicit class IteratorWrapper[T](it: Iterator[T]) {
    def distinct = new Iterator[T] {
        var seen = Set.empty[T]
        var ahead = Option.empty[T]

        def searchAhead {
            while (ahead.isEmpty && it.hasNext) {
                val v = it.next
                if (!seen(v)) {
                    seen += v
                    ahead = Some(v)
                }
            }
        }

        def hasNext = {
            searchAhead
            ahead.nonEmpty
        }

        def next = {
            searchAhead
            val result = ahead.get
            ahead = None
            result
        }
    }
}
```

Be aware that, as it is usually so with Iterators, the original iterator is not valid after calling `.distinct` on it.

Comment: This is wrong! Consider: `Iterator(1, 1)`. After calling `next` for the first time, `hasNext` will still be true, but calling `next` will actually throw.

Comment: I have done exactly that and everything is fine as it should be. http://pastebin.com/NPAjq2aS

Comment: Well yes... because you are calling next on the original iterator, not the one created by the call to `distinct`.

Comment: I have fixed the problem. The consequence is that even `.hasNext` can mutate the iterator, as there is no way of telling whether the distinct iterator has any elements left, you have to peek.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job (but I hate):

```
class UniqueIterable[T](i: Iterable[T]) extends Iterable[T] {
  import scala.collection.mutable.Set
  def iterator = new Iterator[T] {
    val it = i.iterator
    var nextE: Option[T] = None
    val seen: Set[T] = Set.empty
    def hasNext = {
      popNext()
      nextE.isDefined
    }
    def next = {
      popNext()
      val res = nextE.get
      nextE = None
      res
    }

    @tailrec
    private def popNext() {
      if (nextE.isEmpty && it.hasNext) {
        val n = it.next
        if (seen contains n) popNext()
        else {
          seen += n
          nextE = Some(n)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```