# Implement DISTINCT in for comprehension

Tags: sql, scala, for-comprehension

In the penultimate lecture of [his Coursera course](https://class.coursera.org/progfun-004/), Prof. Odersky offered the following `for` comprehension as the final step in a lovely case study:

```
def solutions(target: Int): Stream[Path] =
  for {
    pathSet <- pathSets
    path <- pathSet
    if path.endState contains target
  } yield path
```

In an earlier lecture he drew some analogies between `for` comprehensions and SQL.

What I'm looking for is a way to `yield` only those `path`s that have a `DISTINCT` `endState`.

Is there a way to refer back from within a filter clause of the same comprehension to the items that have already been yielded?

Another approach might be to convert `pathSets` to a `Map` from `endState` to `path` before the `for` statement, then convert it back to a `Stream` before returning it. However, this would seem to lose the lazy computation benefits of using a `Stream`.

An earlier method from the same case study accomplished similar goals, but it was already a recursive function, while this one doesn't (seem to) need to be recursive.

It looks like I could use a mutable `Set` to track the `endState`s that get yielded, but that feels unsatisfying, since the course has successfully avoided using mutability so far.

Comment: You could use a recursive Stream definition but you couldn't use a for-comprehension then of course...

Comment: Using `mutable.Set` would indeed be easy and efficient. Why does it trouble you so much? `map` and `flatMap` are also implemented with mutability, even though you use them with that `for`. So there is mutability in your function anyways, but an outsider has no power to use that mutability and that is what matters. It can also make your code more readable. mutability is not the devil :)

Comment: Would you be able to use the distinct method of Stream à la [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16197092/how-to-get-distinct-items-from-a-scala-iterable-maintaining-laziness)?

Comment: That's an interesting feature of Streams. However, it appears that it has to be an entire object == comparison to match with distinct. In this case, what I want to dump is any following items for which the `endState` attribute has already been seen.

Comment: If you've done the last assignment of the course, if I remember correctly there was a function where exactly this action was to be implemented, and it was done using an accumulator that contained end states seen so far and a helper function that filtered based on that. It's very much doable.

Comment: What I would really like is for the Scala language to natively support this extension to comprehensions, such that one of the filters in the comprehension would be able to access the results that had already been yielded by that same comprehension, enabling not only a `DISTINCT` based on `==` (as supported already by Streams), but a `DISTINCT` that is based on a custom function, in this case comparing attributes of the things that have already been yielded.

Comment: There's no need to add native support for distinct, and one of the main ideas of Scala is that you should be able to write the extensions you need in the language itself and they will look like primitives of the language. If you want to be fully immutable you need some kind of state monad transformer composed with the Stream monad

Comment: The only way I think distinct will work is by keeping state, whether you do that in a mutable map, or abstract it away in monads

Comment: Do I understand you correctly with this simplified example? `val values = Seq(1, 2, 3, 4); for { value <- values; if !(__ contains 6) } yield value * 2` where `__` refers back to the values yielded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to refer back from within a filter clause of the same comprehension to the items that have already been yielded?

Your for comprehension desugars to something more or less like

```
pathSets flatMap {
  pathSet => pathSet filter {
   path => path.endState contains target
  }
} map {path => path}
```

The last map with an identity function is your yield. I can't remember if the spec allows that map to be elided when it's an identity function.

Anyway, I hope this shows more clearly why there's no "reaching back" with that structure.

You can write a lazy, recursive distinctBy function

```
implicit class DistinctStream[T](s: Stream[T]) {
  def distinctBy[V](f: T => V): Stream[T] = {
    def distinctBy(remainder: Stream[T], seen:Set[V]): Stream[T] =
      remainder match {
        case head #:: tail => 
          val value = f(head)
          if (seen contains value) distinctBy(tail, seen)
          else Stream.cons(head, distinctBy(tail, seen + value))
        case empty => empty
     }

    distinctBy(s, Set())  
  }
}
```

And use it like so

```
def solutions(target: Int): Stream[Path] =
(for {
 pathSet <- pathSets
 path <- pathSet
 if path.endState contains target
} yield path) distinctBy (_.endState)
```

Yeah, now there's recursion. But there already was because Stream's map, flatMap, and filter functions are all lazy recursive functions already.